# Tortoise SVN Error: OPTIONS of [server] could not connect

Tags: tortoise-svn

I'm getting this error and no idea how to resolve it, it worked fine until a couple of days ago.
Error: OPTIONS of 'http://aws-fileserver.aws.lan:8080/svn/svn/': could
not connect to server (http://aws-fileserver.aws.lan:8080)

anyone has any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Are there meant to be two `/svn`'s?

Comment: well, I haven't touched it, so I guess so